# How to use the pre-trained word2vec hex file in R and h2o

Tags: r, h2o

How to use the .hex file provided by https://s3.amazonaws.com/tomk/h2o-world/megan/w2v.hex and build a word2vec model using R and h2o.

Answer (score 0):

The file you posted corresponds to a tutorial that was created which includes a [README.md](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/ca7533e76eb4152a93b37d8e769e8f808c8d59ac/h2o-world-2017/nlp/README.md) and [Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/h2o-world-2017/nlp/AmazonReviews.ipynb). While the tutorial is in Python the naming conventions between R and Python are generally similar enough that if you look at the R API [DOCs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/index.html), you should be able to figure out the equivalent code in R.

From a similar word2vec tutorial from the same tutorials repo, here is a close equivalent to the Python Tutorial for [R](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/training/h2o_3_hands_on/nlp/WordEmbeddings.R).